# why I am getting this error while installing : pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz

Tags: python, python-3.7, anaconda3, pyspider

why Iam getting this error

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\kodal\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kodal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-odzer82v\\pyobjc-framework-Quartz\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kodal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-odzer82v\\pyobjc-framework-Quartz\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\kodal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-odzer82v\pyobjc-framework-Quartz\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\kodal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-odzer82v\pyobjc-framework-Quartz\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\kodal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-odzer82v\pyobjc-framework-Quartz\setup.py", line 67, in <module>
        py_limited_api=True,
      File "C:\Users\kodal\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-odzer82v\pyobjc-framework-Quartz\pyobjc_setup.py", line 420, in Extension
        if "clang" in get_config_var("CC"):
    TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess here, but your traceback shows that you're on Windows, but pyobjc-framework-Quartz is a macOS framework. That same command worked fine on my macOS machine.